# How to cut Java for each loop in half?

Tags: java, loops

I'm working a lot with for each loops in Java. I'm using them to make every class of my objects to do "drawing", but it takes a lot of memory so I want to cut it in half, is there a way to do for each loop not for a full list?

```
for(Tile tile: tiles){
tile.draw();
}
```

I want to:

```
for(Tile tile: (half of)tiles){
    tile.draw();
}
```

is it possible or I just need to get lenght of tiles and when it reaches the number break the loop?

Comment: How do you want to cut it in half? E.g., taking every alternate tile, or just the first half, ... or in some other way?

Comment: I want to do just half of the list of "tiles" and when needed do other half.
so right now the first half.

Comment: How is this going to save you memory? Is the second half of the list redundant? Does the drawing operation take up memory proportionally to the number of tiles drawn?

Comment: i will save memory by cutin list into chunks so when im in one side i go through onli part of the list not every 5000+ tiles

Comment: @TautvydasJalinskas that's probably not true. Going through a list doesn't mean that there's an extra copy of each item in the list in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've clarified that you have an `ArrayList`, you can use the `subList` function to get a view of the first half of the list

```
for(Tile tile: tiles.subList(0, tiles.size()/2){
  tile.draw();
}
```

This uses a `foreach` loop and is pretty succinct and readable code.

Because the sub-list is just a view over the original list, there's no penalty copying to a new list.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always the old-style `for` loop. Assuming that `tiles` is an instance of `List<Tile>`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size() / 2; i++)
{
  tiles.get(i).draw();
}
```

Or, if you want to keep the iterator order:

```
Iterator<Tile> iter = tiles.iterator();
int i = 0;
int halfway = tiles.size() / 2;
while(i < halfway)
{
  Tile tile = iter.next();
  tile.draw();
  i++;
}
```

Comment: This assumes it's an `ArrayList`, really, because if it's a `LinkedList`, the operation is *not* equivalent to using the list iterator as a foreach loop does.

Comment: It's ok. He assumed correctly and this could help, so i will upvote.

Comment: @shekharsuman : without making assumptions, this question is unanswerable. All answers so far have made assumptions that OP did not specify.

Comment: @RealSkeptic is correct. I added an alternative that preserves the order of the original iterator.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to do just half of the list of "tiles" and when needed do other half.

If it does not matter in what order you do the halves, you could do it like this:

```
int counter = 0;
for(Tile tile: tiles) {
    if (counter++ % 2 == 0) {
        tile.draw();
    }
}
```

Do `counter++ %2 == 1` for the other half.

Answer (score 2):

Oooh, there are several ways to do that.

**JAVA**

```
final List<Tile> tiles = .... // create the list of Tile instances
//Be sure that tiles is not empty before to do that
final List<Tile> firstHalfSubList=tiles.subList(0, tiles.size()/2);
final List<Tile> secondHalfSubList=tiles.subList(tiles.size()/2, tiles.length());
```

Observe that the two half list are backing tiles, so make them immutable.

But my favourite is by using Guava library

**GUAVA**

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.math.IntMath;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

final List<Tile> tiles = .... // create the list of Tile instances
final int partitionSize = IntMath.divide(tile.size(), 2, RoundingMode.UP);
final List<List<Tile>> partitions = Lists.partition(tile, partitionSize);
```

and you have a list of two partitions and you can iterate over them!

Comment: The Guava approach is beautiful!

Comment: I think so. Guava is an excellent library, and Java8 took a lot of its great ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given here already seem fine to me, but I noticed in your question that you wanted to have a for-each loop. So you could use stream to halve the list:

```
List<Tile> halve =tiles.stream().limit(tiles.size()/2).collect(Collectors.toList());
for(Tile tile : halve)
{   
}
```

This is the same approach as the other answers, just a point of style-choice